# How can i delete the 13.2gb photo library off of my phone?

Tags: photos

I have already gone through the creating an empty folder and synced just that folder and when that didn't work I unselected the box to sync photos and that also did not resolve my issue.  I'm at a loss on how to remove the data from my iPhone5.  I currently have 250 photos/videos on my phone that are just over 2gb...I would really appreciate help clearing out such a large portion of my harddrive

Comment: Did you shoot these photos with your iPhone or have they been synced over via iTunes?

Answer (score -1):

Try going to iCloud settings on the phone and turn off the Photos Sync setting. Then delete the photos from the phone.